# WPF Crash with no stacktrace

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a big application that randomly throws an exception.
This exception has no reproduction path, and no clear stacktrace in the logs:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.RestoreLiveShaping()
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at FullDownloadManager.App.Main()
```

As you can see it is a concurrency problem with some collection being changed while UI thread refreshes and iterates through the list.

The problem is to find where is it happening since there is no track of where it occurred.

Does anyone knows a way to detect where this exception is being thrown?

Thanks,

**Update:**
I'm reviewing all bingings to collections of my program and I found an interesting scenario that might be the reason:

First I have a CollectionViewSource bound with an ObservableCollection

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="deviceViewSource" Source="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=Devices}"
                          IsLiveGroupingRequested="True">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription Converter="{StaticResource deviceGroupConverter}" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

As the Source is Syncrhonized it might not be a problem. Note that I set LiveGrouping to true

Now it's the interesting part:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource deviceViewSource}, Path=Groups}"
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                . . . 
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
                      . . .
                </ItemsControl>
             </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If **Items** or **Groups** of CollectionViewSource is not thread-safe, I might have a problem??

**Update2:**
I confirmed that the problem is with CollectionViewSource and Groupping.
Since I couldn't solve this problem, my solution was to manually group and sync the UI.

As suggested **BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization** might solve this issue but I haven't tried.

Anyway, it's weird that CollectionViewSource is not thread-safe, even tough I'm using an ObservableCollection as a Source.

Comment: Do you ever change anything in other threads?

Comment: Yes, there are many lists being modified in background. I synchronize in a lock or via dispatcher all of them. Maybe I missed some. I want to identify which one

Comment: Using a lock is not good enough.  Any list which is bound to the UI must only be updated on the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, you're right.. I always use ObservableCollections which can only be editted in the UI thread. Anyway, is there any way to identify where this exception is thrown? It's weird that this stacktrace doesnt provide me the location.

Comment: The exception is from the UI thread reacting to the incorrect change.  The Locals Window in the debugger may help you diagnose.

Comment: Thanks Slaks, I updated my answer, can you take a look please?

Comment: @RenatoDegelo The stack trace does tell you pretty much exactly where the failure occurred - in UI framework code; it's just not useful to your investigation. Some bit of threaded code altered a collection (successfully), and then the UI code noticed it and threw the exception. There is no "footprint" the environment or toolchain can follow for you. At best, you need to figure out which visual element is associated with the exception and then figure out which collection is bound to it to work your way back to the possible culprit.

Comment: You must make sure that you never raise any change event that will be handled by WPF data binding on any other thread.

Comment: @Zenilogix Thanks you for the comment, as I explained in the question. I understand what the problem is, I'm just having trouble to identify where is it. I want to know if there is any better way to investigate this issue.

Comment: you could try and toy around with the debug options in Visual Studio. I'm pretty sure there is a checkbox that causes Visual Studio to break on exceptions inside .NET code. (also verify that you set Visual Studio to break on every unhandled exception). When the exception is thrown just examine the stack trace window and you should find the responsible list. From there on out you should be able to find out the method that modifies the list while the view enumerates it.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler I tried that, but stacktrace looks same, and there is no clue of where it was thrown.

Comment: @SLaks, I tried looking at Locals, but nothing in there

Comment: Look at each stack frame to see if there are any locals.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use

`BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(myCollection, myLockObject);`

That should, at least, eliminate all threading related issues.
This is available since .NET 4.5, just in case you are still using a lower version.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.0. I upvoted you for the interesting approach.

Comment: For .NET 4.0 you could write something like ObservableCollectionEx.
As i don't have my own code for that anymore you could grab it from this website http://xcalibursystems.com/2014/02/making-a-better-observablecollection-part-2-cross-threading/ it looks a lot like my own implementation looked like.